# Apply .htaccess to all subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
root
    folder1
        foldera
            file.php
    folder2
        folderb
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

I would like to route all requests to index.php and have this apply to all folders. Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This seems to work fine for `localhost/root`. The request is correctly routed to index.php. But for `localhost/root/folder1` or `localhost/root/folder1/foldera/filephp` it does not work. Is there an additional rule I need to define for this to work?

Comment: Your rule applies only if the requested path does not exist.

Comment: I have a front controller for an API that all requests will funnel through whether the given path is valid or not. So a request cannot access a path directly. Is there no rule that I can apply at the root .htaccess or do I need to have an .htaccess added to every subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

> The configuration directives found in a .htaccess file are applied to the directory in which the .htaccess file is found, and to all subdirectories thereof. However, it is important to also remember that there may have been .htaccess files in directories higher up. Directives are applied in the order that they are found. Therefore, a .htaccess file in a particular directory may override directives found in .htaccess files found higher up in the directory tree. And those, in turn, may have overridden directives found yet higher up, 
>   or in the main server configuration file itself.

If your htaccess is in the root, why the '../'? As it stands it is redirecting to an index.php above your root directory.

If you want it to work for all requests, remove the two rewrite conditions. Right now it is saying: "rewrite request only if the request is not for a file or a directory that exists".

Comment: Sorry, the ../ was a test I ran. The .htaccess should not include it. I updated my question for accuracy. That makes sense. I'll remove the two rewrite conditions.

Comment: The suggestion below from iainn is a good one. The recursive nature of htaccess makes it easy to break things. Best to avoid that possibility by putting directories that don't need direct http access outside of the web root.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want files in other folders to be directly accessible, it probably makes sense to move them outside of the web root entirely. So your front controller would be in a `web/` subdirectory, and the webserver's docroot would point at that instead.

```
root
    folder1
        foldera
            file.php
    folder2
        folderb
    web <- DocumentRoot should point here
        .htaccess
        index.php
```